# How to remove reference from object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, ractivejs, object-reference

I have an application in ractive.js, and I need to create copy of some data from my component state.
example:

```
const dateGroups = this.get("dateGroups");
this.set("editedPickups.beforeEdit", dateGroups);
```

And I need to remove reference from "editedPickups.beforeEdit" which is targeted to "dateGroups" because if I change something in "dateGroups" it changes in "editedPickups.beforeEdit" too.
I find solution with `JSON.stringify` and `parse`, but this object is big and I don't know who this will be acting.
This example below not working too:

```
const dateGroups = Object.assign({}, this.get("dateGroups"));
```

Comment: You can use [`lodash.cloneDeep()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) to clone all references recursively

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: As far as removing the reference, I don't know ractive, but `this.set("editedPickups.beforeEdit", null);` seems like a reasonable attempt.

Comment: Object.assign should work. Stringfly and parse works fast, its good for big, nested object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you've posted won't work because Object.assign will shallow copy the object (nested props will still hold references to the original object). You can use `lodash.cloneDeep()`.

Comment: Yup. Probably u are right with this, cuz I have other nested object assigned there. I will come back here with an information

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread syntax to create new instant

```
// if dateGroups is an array
this.set("editedPickups.beforeEdit", [...dateGroups]);
// if dateGroups is an object
this.set("editedPickups.beforeEdit", {...dateGroups});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score -1):

With ES6, you can remove an object reference by using the `...` syntax.

```js
const objectWeWantToCopyButNotReference = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

const myNewObject = { ...objectWeWantToCopyButNotReference }

myNewObject.foo = 'not bar'

console.log('my new object has changed:', myNewObject.foo)

console.log('original object not changed: ', objectWeWantToCopyButNotReference.foo)
```